# How to call a model from view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, model

Hi i am trying to call a model from view but i am getting error as.

```
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: 
CI_Loader::$Stopsmap_Model Filename: stopsmap/index.php Line Number: 59
```

i tryed this below code in view.But no luck

```
foreach ($routes as $route_details):
//calling model

//$trip_max_min_sequence_details = $this->load->Stopsmap_Model->fullTripdetails($trips->trip_id); i tried this also but same error
//$this->load->model('Stopsmap_Model');
//$data = $this->stopsmap_model->fullTripdetails($route_details->route_id);  i tried this also but same error
$this->load->model('fixedtransit_model/Stopsmap_Model');
$get_route_related_trips = $this->Stopsmap_Model->getRoutetrips($route_details->route_id);
  if(count($get_route_related_trips)>=1):
    echo '1 stop';
  endif;
endforeach;
```

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why don't you call it from the controller which loads the view and pass the variable to the view ?

Comment: !! why do you want to call a model in your view..

Comment: actually there is a list of trips Name .in that there would be stops .I need to show the list of trips name which is having at-lest one stop so I am checking in the foreach loop .u can look in view code

Comment: You are doing it wrong, `Model` in `View`, finish everything in your controller.

Comment: how can i pass trip id dynamically in controller..i need to check every for every root...same model is used in controller its working fine...but why not it working in view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller , you can have like this:

```
function routes(){
  //call model
  $this->load->model('fixedtransit_model/Stopsmap_Model');

  $routes = $this->topsmap_model->get_routes();

  foreach ($routes as $route_details){

   $get_route_related_trips[] = $this->Stopsmap_Model->getRoutetrips($route_details->route_id);

  }

  $data['related_routes'] = $get_route_related_trips;

  //load view and pass data
  $this->load->view('myview' , $data);

}
```

and in your view:

```
<?php foreach($related_routes){

//do something

}
?>
```

Comment: one question my problem is solved now ..but if we able to call model in view lines of code will be less.. can we able to do this in view

Answer (score 0):

on my end
i have created a model named **accountmodel** in applications/models dir
and load in view like (would be best if you load model in your controller):-

```
$this->load->model('AccountModel','Account');
//AccountModel (model class name)
//Account (object) you can further use this model using object
```

for more info :- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html